# Can I make a set of Google Documents to "inherit" scripts stored elsewhere?

Tags: scripting, automation, google-drive-api, google-docs

I'd like to automate work for several documents stored in certain shared folder (G Suite) of my company.

How can I make those Docs (they will be Docs in nearly 99% of the cases) inherit some common behaviour, such as getting tables updated, custom footers added, and the such?

Right now my approach is to have a central Spreadsheet with lots of scripting inside, and it will scan through selected folders and files, doing its work on each of them, but I'm not sure this is the optimal solution

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you can refer to [Document Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/#classes).

> This service allows scripts to create, access, and modify Google Docs
>   files.

There are available [Classes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/#classes) which you can play with to achieve the function you need from your application.

Comment: Thanks! but I am already aware of them, even scripting with them. What I wanted to know if I can build some kind of common .gs file for storing all common data to these documents